# How do I use a proxy for only some specific URLs?

Tags: url, proxy

Like with [FoxyProxy](https://getfoxyproxy.org/), I want to use proxy in emacs only for URLs that match a specific regexp.

E.g., if the URL matches `\\.ec2\\.internal`, I want the [`url-proxy-services`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/url/Proxies.html) to be `"ip-10-0-37-237.ec2.internal:8081"`, otherwise none.

Note that the `no_proxy` key works the other way around - it *excludes* matching URLs from proxy processing, while I want to only *include* some URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package `url-proxy` provides a *defvar* called `url-proxy-locator` that allows you to define your own locator.

```lisp
(defun locate-my-url-proxy (urlobj host)
  (cond
   ((string-match-p "\\.ec2\\.internal" host)
    "PROXY ip-10-0-37-237.ec2.internal:8081")
   (t "DIRECT")))

;;; returns "http://ip-10-0-37-237.ec2.internal:8081/"
(let ((url-proxy-locator #'locate-my-url-proxy)
      (urlobj (url-generic-parse-url "https://sldjf.ec2.internal/jdsklfj")))
  (url-find-proxy-for-url urlobj (url-host urlobj)))
```